# ESXi 5.5: Clone a VM to template using CLI (on Linux)

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, template

How can I clone a VM to a template from Linux CLI. I tried using [VMware vSphere CLI (vCLI)](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?productId=285&downloadGroup=VSP510-VCLI-510) in vain, couldn't find an option to do so.

Comment: Have a look at vmkfstools.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I believe I have to ssh to the ESXi box for that. My goal is to use some API or tool to do it from my Linux VM. Basically, I am trying to do what this [code](https://github.com/Banno/packer-post-processor-vsphere-ova) does using scripts. I have used ovftool to upload the VM to the vCenter. Now, I am looking to clone it to a template.